# Denote $Q(a)$ the sum of digits of $a$, prove the quasi-multiplicity property $Q(ab)\leq Q(a)Q(b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Define $Q(a)$ as the sum of digits.

> I want to prove that for any two integers $a$ and $b$:
> $$
> Q(a b) \leq Q(a) Q(b).
> $$

For this I was able to prove this identity:
$$
Q(a b) \leq \min \{a Q(b), b Q(a)\}.
$$
Now has anyone an idea of how to show the quasi-multiplicity? Note that $Q(n)$ is not the digital root, which is taking $\pmod{9}$.

---

Thanks to @Feng for providing a solution. Here is the proof of the identity $Q(10^za)=Q(a)$ @Feng used:

> Using the index shift rule $$\sum_{k=m+p}^{m+p}a_{k-p}=\sum_{k=m}^{m}a_{k-p}$$ we get $$Q(10^z\cdot a)=Q\left(\sum_{k=0}^ma_k(10^{k+z})\right)=Q\left( \sum_{k=z}^{m+z} a_{k-z}(10^{k})\right) = \sum_{k=z}^{m+z} a_{k-z}=\sum_{k=0}^{m} a_{k} = Q(a)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let's consider a simple case: $a=10m_1+n_1, b=10m_2+n_2$ for some $m_i, n_i\in\{0,1,\cdots, 9\}$, $i=1,2$. Then
\begin{align*}
Q(ab)&=Q(100m_1m_2+10m_2n_1+10m_1n_2+n_1n_2)\\
&\leq Q(100m_1m_2)+Q(10m_2n_1)+Q(10m_1n_2)+Q(n_1n_2)\\
&=Q(m_1m_2)+Q(m_2n_1)+Q(m_1n_2)+Q(n_1n_2)\\
&\leq m_1m_2+m_2n_1+m_1n_2+n_1n_2=Q(a)Q(b).
\end{align*}
We have used the fact that
$$Q(10^na)=Q(a),\qquad Q(a+b)\leq Q(a)+Q(b), \qquad Q(a)\leq a.$$
I think that the generalization of the above procedure should be not hard:

> If $a=\sum_{i=0}^Mm_i10^i, b=\sum_{j=0}^Nn_j10^j$ for some $m_i, n_j\in\{0,1,\cdots, 9\}$, then \begin{align*} Q(ab)&=Q\left(\sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^Nm_in_j10^{i+j}\right)\\&\leq \sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^NQ(m_in_j10^{i+j})=\sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^NQ(m_in_j)\\&\leq \sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^Nm_jn_j=\left(\sum_{i=0}^Mm_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^Nn_j\right)=Q(a)Q(b).\end{align*}